# Flag Exact Word Within a String Using String Contains

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
ID Symptoms
1  ear, fever
2  hearing loss
3  hurt ear
4  spear wound
5  bad hearing  
6  earring cut
```

I want to flag only the records where "ear" appears. So for example, the output would look like this:

```
ID Symptoms         Ear
1  ear, fever        1
2  hearing loss      0
3  hurt ear          1
4  spear wound       0
5  bad hearing       0 
6  earring cut       0
```

I've played around with some code with little success:

Issue: this code would pull anything with the text "ear"

```
LABS_TAT.loc[:,"Ear"]=np.where(LABS_TAT["Symptoms"].str.contains("ear", case=False),1,0)
```

Notice the space after "ear ", this code would not flag the record "hurt ear"

```
 LABS_TAT.loc[:,"Ear"]=np.where(LABS_TAT["Symptoms"].str.contains("ear ", case=False),1,0)
```

Notice the space before " ear", this code would not flag the record "ear, fever"

```
 LABS_TAT.loc[:,"Ear"]=np.where(LABS_TAT["Symptoms"].str.contains(" ear", case=False),1,0)
```

How can I fix my code so that it flags any records with the word "ear"? I feel like there is a simple answer but I'm still somewhat a newb to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with a regex pattern:

```
df['Ear'] = df['Symptoms'].str.contains(r'(?i)\bear\b').astype(int)
```

Result:

```
  ID      Symptoms   Ear
0   1    ear, fever    1
1   2  hearing loss    0
2   3      hurt ear    1
3   4   spear wound    0
4   5   bad hearing    0
5   6   earring cut    0
```

Comment: Thanks does this code imply case=False, or do I need to add that in so it catches "Ear"?

Comment: It already imply `case=False` because we have used the flag `(?i)` (case insensitive match) in regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Since [`.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) takes a regex pattern, this should be as easy as `.contains(r"\bear\b", case=False)`.

`\b` indicates a word-boundry character. You can read more about regular expressions in the [Python standard library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).